# Creating an Array from a text file with more than one data type

Tags: java, arrays

First some background:

The main method will drive your program by doing the following:
•Create an array to hold all the individual golfers and par scores (type is Golfer[ ]).
•Prompt the user for a data file containing the Par scores and the player names and score. The format of the input file should look like:

> Par, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4
>
> George, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4
>
> Paul, 4, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 4, 3, 5
>
> Ringo, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4
>
> John, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Main 

{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    boolean tryAgain;

       do
       {
           Scanner console = new Scanner( System.in );
           System.out.print( "Please enter a file name to read: " );
           String inFile = console.next();
           tryAgain = false;

           try
           {
               File file = new File( inFile );     
               Scanner tokens = new Scanner( file ); 

                int data[][];
                String str = "";

               for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
               {
                   for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                   {

                       int value = tokens.nextInt();


                   }
                   System.out.printf("\n");
               }

               tokens.close();

               String people [] = str.split(",");
               Golfer golfers = new Golfer(null, null);
           }


           catch (IOException e)
           {
               System.out.printf("Error opening file %s, %s\n", inFile, e);
               tryAgain = true;
           }
       }
       while (tryAgain);


}
```

I am unsure of how to properly use a nested for loop to pull the data and store it in an array since there are two data types.  And... I guess any suggestions on how to store the information in my Golfer class couldn't hurt. I am a beginner so any complicated techniques should probably be avoided.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You need a single type; `Golfer`. Perhaps write a method to parse a single line into a `Golfer`.

Comment: put it on a Object then use `instanceof` in a condition :)

Comment: I am sorry but I am not quite sure how to do either of those things properly.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, a single time needs to be created to hold all of the data from a single line, such as name, and an array to hold all of the scores for that particular golfer.

```
while(tokens.hasNext()) {
    String input = token.nextLine();
    String [] splitGolfer = input.split(",");
    Golfer newGolfer = new Golfer();
    newGolfer.name = splitGolfer[0];
    ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i= 1; i < splitgolfer.length; i++) {
        scores.add(Integer.valueOf(splitGolfer[i]);
    }
    newGolfer.scores = scores;
```

Golfer class:

```
String name;
ArrayList<Integer> scores;
```

Comment: You may want to split by ", "

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the suitable solution for you. Change variables, filename and directory as per your requirement.
It will throw an exception if any line in the file will have a different format than what you have mentioned above (player's name followed by scores).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Golfer
{
    //arraylist of all lines from given files (players data).
    ArrayList<String> theData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String playerName;
    private ArrayList<Integer> parScores;

    //you must read each line in the golder file and send it individually to this method.
    public Golfer() throws IOException
   {
        String fileName = "players.txt";
        theData = readFile(fileName);
        for (String s : theData)
        {
            getPlayerData(s);
        }
    }

    public void getPlayerData(String data)
    {
        String[] list = data.split(",");
        playerName = list[0];
        parScores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for( int i = 1; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            parScores.add(Integer.parseInt(list[i]));
        }
    }

    //This method will read your data file and will return arraylist (one array for each player).
    public ArrayList<String> readFile(String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        //don't forget to add directory name here if you have, because we are only passing filename, not directory.
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        String temp = in.readLine(); 
        while (temp != null)
        {
            data.add(temp);
            temp = in.readLine();
        }
        in.close();
        return data;
    }
}
```